# if A*=2A, then A=0

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, matrix-decomposition

let A be a matrix of size n×n such that A* = 2A. prove that A=0

Suppose that $A^* =2A$ and r is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $Ax=rx$ for some eigenvector x

$$r(x,x) = (rx,x)=(Ax,x)=(x,A^*x)=(x,2Ax)=2(A^*x,x)=4(Ax,x)$$
So, 
$$(Ax,x)=4(Ax,x) \implies
(A-4A)(x,x)=0 \implies 
-3A=0 $$
then $A=0$.

Is it right?

Comment: Is $A^*=$ transpose of the conjugate of A?

Comment: yes A* is the conjugate

Comment: @arwa is it **the transpose of** the conjugate, or is it simply the conjugate?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom the conjugate transpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see now you want a solution verification. Your solution is correct up until you say that $(Ax,x)=4(Ax,x)\implies (A-4A)(x,x)=0$. All that you can conclude is $((A-4A)x,x)=0$, but you cannot "pull out" the $(A-4A)$. You could do this if $(A-4A)$ was a scalar, but here it is a matrix. I do not know if your exact method can be salvaged.

---

#### Hint

Using the relation $A^*=2A$, what can you deduce about $(A^{*})^{*}$? Use this, and the fact that $(A^*)^*=A$, to prove $A=0$. If you use only the equations I have stated, without using any vectors $x$ or inner products $(Ax,x)$, then you can find a very short proof.

Comment: I used it and I have the same result

Comment: @arwaalqwasmah See edits for some more detail.